# FQDN on Azure Service Fabric on Premise

Tags: cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

I don't see a way to configure the cluster FQDN for On Premise installation.
I create a 6 nodes cluster (each nodes running on a physical server) and I'm only able to contact each node on their own IP instead of contacting the cluster on a "general FQDN". With this model, I'm to be are of which node is up, and which node is down.

Does somebody know how to achieve it, based on the sample configurations files provided with Service Fabric standalone installation package?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We're having the exact same problems that you described using the Microsoft Load Balancer and accessing port 19000.

Comment: Hello. No, I change my model to avoid to access the 19000 port directly (from outside the cluster). I make all call from outside through the reverseproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a network load balancer to your infrastructure for that. This will be used to route traffic to healthy nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said I'm not on Azure but OnPremise. Is it a specific network load balancer advisable for Service Fabric ?

Comment: It can be any load balancer solution you like. If it's in Azure / cloud, you'll need a VPN too. You can also add hardware.

Comment: Ok, I test it successfuly with the Microsoft LoadBalancer. Thanks !

Comment: While I continue my test using the FQDN and it doesn't work as expected. I can access the Service Fabric Explorer console through the FQDN, I can access the reverse proxy through the FQDN, but the port 19000 is not accessible through the FQDN. I need it to use the FabricClient in c# to do some service partition resolving. If I connect the FabricClient directly on one node, it works, but through the cluster FQDN. I configure the Microsoft LoadBalancer for all ports, TCP and UDP. What do I have to change in the configuration to let it works ? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a secured cluster? if so, you'll need to provide the client certificate while connecting

Comment: The cluster is not secured, for now I create it only for test. What I see is that service fabric bind all ports on 0.0.0.0 but not the port 19000 : this one bind only the declared node IP. So, perhaps there is something to configure on ServiceFabric to let it bind 19000 on 0.0.0.0 or, if not, the only way I see is too add an external LoadBalancer and not to use the integrated "Microsoft Network Load Balancing" that use a virtual IP.

Comment: if you're running server 2016, try software load balancing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/sdn/technologies/network-function-virtualization/software-load-balancing--slb--for-sdn

Comment: Yes I do the my test on 2016 server, but the final target (on ours customers) will be both 2016 and 2012 R2. I will try to remove the use of the FabricClient API from my code. Thanks for your answers !